# how to get primefaces datatable columns order and width from ManagedBean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, dynamic-columns

i'm using primefaces 4.0, JSF Mojarra 2.2.2
and here is my datatable code :

```
<p:dataTable id="tabexam"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             var="exam"
             value="#{dyna.examViewDataModel}"
             widgetVar="examTable"
             emptyMessage="aucun résultat trouvé pour votre recherche"
             paginator="true"
             rows="40" 
             selection="#{dyna.selectedExamen}"
             filteredValue="#{dyna.filteredexams}"
             selectionMode="single"
             resizableColumns="true"  
             draggableColumns="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="40,80,120">

<p:columns value="#{datatableBean.table}"
           var="column"
           headerText="#{column.userListname}"
           rendered="#{column.visible}"
           resizable="#{column.resizable}"
           width="#{column.width}"
           columnIndexVar="colIndex">

   <h:panelGroup>
             <p:outputLabel value="#{column.dbname}" styleClass="fonty"/>
   </h:panelGroup>

 </p:columns>

</p:dataTable>
```

Here what I've tried so far, but I get empty Strings for getHeaderText in the console and empty width too, i wonder what i'm missing

```
UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    DataTable tabler = (DataTable) view.findComponent(":form1:tabexam");
    List<UIColumn> coler = tabler.getColumns();

    for (int i = 0; i < coler.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("/////////////////");
        System.out.println(coler.get(i).getValueExpression("headerText").getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext()));
        System.out.println(coler.get(i).getHeaderText());
        System.out.println(coler.get(i).isRendered());
        System.out.println(coler.get(i).isResizable());
        System.out.println(coler.get(i).getWidth());
        System.out.println("/////////////////");

    }
 System.out.println(coler.size());
```

Note that `coler.size()` gives the number of columns shown on the datatable.
but the `coler.get(i).getHeaderText()` always gives empty String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are mistaking something:

1. do not nest `p:column` inside `p:columns`
2. DataTable.getColumns does not return what you expect:

   ```
   public List<UIColumn> getColumns() {
       if(columns == null) {
           columns = new ArrayList<UIColumn>();
           FacesContext context = getFacesContext();
           char separator = UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context);

           for(UIComponent child : this.getChildren()) {
               if(child instanceof Column) {
                   columns.add((UIColumn) child);
               }
               else if(child instanceof Columns) {
                   Columns uiColumns = (Columns) child;
                   String uiColumnsClientId = uiColumns.getClientId(context);

                   for(int i=0; i < uiColumns.getRowCount(); i++) {
                       DynamicColumn dynaColumn = new DynamicColumn(i, uiColumns);
                       dynaColumn.setColumnKey(uiColumnsClientId + separator + i);
                       columns.add(dynaColumn);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return columns;
   }
   ```

this returns a synthetic emulation: only `columnKey` per column, and, as you stated, the correct number of columns.

generally speaking, `p:columns` is ONE component and when you access it from controller layer, you have to refer to its DECLARATION (single component) instead of its REPRESENTATION (multiple columns)

1. since you are backing `p:columns` with your `#{datatableBean.table}` you should already have all the information you are trying to get from DataTable component, in a reverse-engineered fashion.

**update**

oh, now i realize what you want to do. you have to use event listeners for that.

from PF showcase:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" widgetVar="cars" draggableRows="true">  

    <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{tableBean.onColReorder}" update=":some:component" />  

    <p:ajax event="colResize" listener="#{tableBean.onColResize}" update=":some:component"/>    

    <!-- columns here -->  
</p:dataTable>
```

listening for these events in backing bean and mantain these informations should solve your problem

**update 2**

whew, it was not simple at all.

due to Primefaces bug for dynamic column resizing (at least for my tries) and incomplete column reordering event implementation, this is what came out:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGroup id="model">
        <ui:repeat var="column2" value="#{testBean.columnList2}">
            <div>#{column2.title} - #{column2.width}</div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:dataTable var="elem" value="#{testBean.elementList}" resizableColumns="true" draggableColumns="true">
        <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{testBean.onColumnReorder}" update=":form:model" />  
        <p:ajax event="colResize" listener="#{testBean.onColumnResize}" update=":form:model"/>  

        <c:forEach var="column" items="#{testBean.columnList}">
            <p:column headerText="#{column.title}" rendered="#{column.visible}" width="#{column.width}">
                <f:attribute name="myCol" value="#{column}"/>
                <span>#{elem[column.property]}</span>
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

and this bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<MyColumn> columnList;
    private List<MyColumn> columnList2;
    private List<MyElement> elementList;

    public class MyColumn
    {
        private String title;
        private String property;
        private boolean visible = true;
        private boolean resizable = true;
        private int width = 100;

        public MyColumn(String title, String property, boolean visible, boolean resizable, int width)
        {
            super();
            this.title = title;
            this.property = property;
            this.visible = visible;
            this.resizable = resizable;
            this.width = width;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }

    public class MyElement
    {
        private String code;
        private String name;
        private String type;

        public MyElement(String code, String name, String type)
        {
            super();
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        columnList = new ArrayList<>();
        columnList.add(new MyColumn("element code", "code", true, true, 100));
        columnList.add(new MyColumn("element name", "name", true, true, 100));
        columnList.add(new MyColumn("element type", "type", true, true, 100));

        columnList2 = new ArrayList<>(columnList);

        elementList = new ArrayList<>();
        elementList.add(new MyElement("001", "foo", "normal"));
        elementList.add(new MyElement("002", "bar", "strange"));
        elementList.add(new MyElement("003", "xyz", "normal"));
        elementList.add(new MyElement("004", "abc", "nothing"));
    }

    public void onColumnResize(ColumnResizeEvent event)
    {
        UIColumn column = event.getColumn();
        int width = event.getWidth();

        UIComponent colComponent = (UIComponent) column;
        MyColumn myCol = (MyColumn) colComponent.getAttributes().get("myCol");

        myCol.setWidth(width);
    }

    public void onColumnReorder(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();

        columnList2.clear();

        for(UIColumn column : table.getColumns())
        {
            UIComponent colComponent = (UIComponent) column;

            MyColumn myCol = (MyColumn) colComponent.getAttributes().get("myCol");
            columnList2.add(myCol);
        }
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

updated code, you can find ordered columns in `columnList2`. now are also shown in the form.
now you can use `columnList2` to store oreder and widths to db.

Comment: I understand, but #{datatableBean.table} is only a ColumnModel that i have created my self, so you suggest that i need to bind the Columns to a requestScoped bean, then i will be able to get the changes made on the datatable columns order after dragging,width, etc..

Comment: Michele that was a brilliant way to listen to the drag and drop action .I've tested it and it works like a charm " <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{datatableBean.showdatatblecolumnspec()}" update=":form1:msg" />" but my real problem is how can i get the final Columns order after the drag and drop was made.(eg: before drag : 1/car,2/model,3/year ; after drag : 1/car,3/year,2/model) so i need to save this into database so when user connects, gets the same columns order.

Comment: thanks, but it's Primefaces merit, not mine :) you should maintain a model in your bean and update that model with changes from events. maybe the same List<Column> suits. your choice if you want to commit this model on db on each event, or commit when user, for example, press a button.

Comment: i've tesetd this but after onColumnReorder() is invoked i get NPE on columnList.get(1).getTitle();

Comment: Brilliant and neat :)

Comment: i wonder if i can get all the columns even the hidden ones , what do you think ?

Comment: it is up to you. when a column is not rendered it can't be ordered. i'd not save not-rendered columns to db, otherwise i'd put them at the bottom of the list.

Comment: but i need to maintain the order of not-rendered columns relatively to rendered column for future show on exact order, that is my big challenge :(

Comment: it's simply impossible if you don't have an order rule. ie, if you have 5 columns there are 5! = 120 possible orders. now you have 3 hidden columns and 2 visible. user orders the 2 visible columns, and you have to choose one from (5 - 2)! = 6 possible orders. as i said, you need a rule to choose one.

Comment: well i can compare them with string value and old order and extract a new full ordered column, i just need to know the loop condition, i have two array one with ordered visible columns, and a master array, what i want is to extract a new ordered array which a fusion of the two, quite difficult.

Comment: how about moving the f:attribute somewhere where it is always taken in consideration in visible or non visible columns, or adding attribute or some component or a trick of yours.