# Accessing dynamic dataTable columns in the backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable with dynamic columns, column reordering on and a columnToggler to control which columns are currently visible. It looks like this:

```
        <p:dataTable id="dashboard-edition-table" widgetVar="dashboardEditTableWidget" value="#{dashboardEditionBean.selectedDashboard.deviceMocks}" var="deviceMock"
            draggableColumns="true">
            <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{dashboardEditionBean.onReorder}" />
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{dashboardEditionBean.selectedDashboard.name}

                <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
                <p:columnToggler datasource="dashboard-edition-table" trigger="toggler">
                    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{dashboardEditionBean.onToggle}" />
                </p:columnToggler>
                <br />
            </f:facet>
            <p:columns value="#{dashboardEditionBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" sortBy="#{deviceMock[column.property]}" filterBy="#{deviceMock[column.property]}"
                visible="#{column.visible}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{deviceMock[column.property]}" />
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
```

As you can see I have listeners for reorder and toggle events. In these listeners I am trying to access the dataTable and print all the columns.

```
public void onReorder(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
    System.out.println("REORDER");
    for (UIColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
        System.out.println("key: " + column.getColumnKey() + ", field:" + column.getField() + ", headerText: "
                        + column.getHeaderText() + ", visible: " + column.isVisible());
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why I get this output in the console:

```
key: dashboard-edition-form:dashboard-edition-table:j_idt87:3, field:null, headerText: null, visible: false
key: dashboard-edition-form:dashboard-edition-table:j_idt87:4, field:null, headerText: null, visible: false
key: dashboard-edition-form:dashboard-edition-table:j_idt87:5, field:null, headerText: null, visible: false
key: dashboard-edition-form:dashboard-edition-table:j_idt87:6, field:null, headerText: null, visible: false
key: dashboard-edition-form:dashboard-edition-table:j_idt87:7, field:null, headerText: null, visible: false
```

As you can see somehow in the backing bean columns have empty headers and visibility set to false DESPITE they are rendered properly in the view (each column has a proper header and is visible).
Why is this happening? I would really appreciate an answer to this question.

Comment: is this elligagble as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531546/how-to-get-primefaces-datatable-columns-order-and-width-from-managedbean ?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, you are right, but it seems that unfortunatly the final answer does not work since you can't cast primefaces DynamicColumn to an UIComponent.

Comment: @Kukeltje ok, it's working but with c:forEach and p:column instead of p:columns. I just wonder how to handle the toggler now.

Comment: Like in the showcase? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml?

Comment: I meant that I want to access toggler changes in the backing bean too. Similar thing to the reorder issue.

Comment: What is wrong with the toggle event?

Comment: It's listener does not reflect the visibility changes at the backing bean side, but I think I know how to handle that. Thank you for your help!